# Compare the quality of distribution fits

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, gamma-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two random variables $A$ and $B$ they are of different size. Both are well fitted as $\gamma$ distributions. My question is to find which one is more gamma like.

**Could You help me to solve this problem?**

Just example code in Matlab:

```
N=10^5;
A = abs(gamrnd(6.2,0.16,N,1)+rand(N,1)*0.07);
B = abs(gamrnd(6.8,0.15,0.7*N,1)+rand(0.7*N,1)*0.05);

pdA = fitdist(A,'Gamma');
pdB = fitdist(B,'Gamma');

[~, pvalA] = kstest(A,'CDF',pdA);
[~, pvalB] = kstest(B,'CDF',pdB);
```

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28431/what-are-good-data-visualization-techniques-to-compare-distributions/274058#274058