# Statistical test for comparing two frequency distributions expressed as arrays (buckets) of values

Tags: r, distributions, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

I am looking for an appropriate statistical test that will compare two frequency distributions, where the data is in the form of two arrays (or buckets) of values.

For example, suppose I have two distributions, where A, B, and C are observed outcomes from a software logging system (such as whether customers clicked on button A, B, or C).

```
HISTORICAL: 
A        B        C
122319   295701   101195

ONE MONTH:
A        B        C
1734     3925     1823
```

My goal is to create an automated A/B testing system. For example, we've collected this data for the last 6 months (in the `HISTORICAL` data set). After we roll out a new algorithm, we can collect new results (in the `ONE MONTH` data set). If the two distributions are "significantly" different, we'd then know to take some action.

My specific questions:

1. What's the proper statistical test for this problem, and how could I know when these distributions differ significantly? An answer using `R` or `python` would be appreciated.
2. What's the minimum number of samples I'd need for both `HISTORICAL` and `ONE MONTH` for the test to be valid?

I've read several other questions related to chi-squared and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests but don't know where to begin. Related questions:

- [How to compare two samples of frequencies with categorical x values where one is subset of the other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79056/how-to-compare-two-samples-of-frequencies-with-categorical-x-values-where-one-is)
- [Assessing the significance of differences in distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4/assessing-the-significance-of-differences-in-distributions)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think the answer is no, but it's worth double checking -- those "One month" values are not included in the "Historical" set, is that right? Are the categories ordered (A<B<C or A>B>C) or unordered (nominal)? (for example if the buttons corresponded to a sequence of options like increasing dollar amounts that would be different than if they were choices of colors)  In your actual application the number of categories is small?  (3 or 4 is small but 20-30 isn't, and for ordered categories my advice would change somewhere in between, but perhaps as low as between 4 and 5)

Comment: This setting--data are logged and the question is "how could I know *when*"--appears to call for a *sequential* test.  Neither $\chi^2$ nor KS tests (as usually applied) would be appropriate, although likely either could be adapted for the purpose.

Comment: What do you intend with "for a test to be valid" there? Are you just asking about the accuracy of nominal significance levels?

Comment: @Glen_b: The "one month" values are not part of the "historical" set. The categories are not ordered. There are usually under 10 categories, usually on order of 4-6.

Comment: @whuber: I'm not really asking for "when" but rather "if". I collected "historical" data for January 1 to June 30, and then I have "one month" data of July 1 to July 31. Now I want to know if these distributions differ.

Comment: @Glen_b: "What do you intend with "for a test to be valid" there": I want to know how many samples I need in both "historical" and "one month" for a given test to be valid.

Comment: You've simply repeated the phrase "for a [given] test to be valid" without explaining what kind of validity you're asking about.  What is it that you mean by "valid" there? What kind of non-validity (which you say changes with sample size) are your concerned with?

Comment: @Glen_b: Just forget I mentioned that. I would just like to know how many samples I would need to achieve statistical significance or confidence at a certain level.

Comment: Are you after a general formula that relates sample size to effect size and significance level, or do you need a specific sample size from a particular effect size and significance level?

Answer (score 2):

Run a [chi-squared goodness-of-fit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) to determine if an observed frequency distribution `observed` differs from a desired (perhaps theoretical) distribution `expected`.

Note carefully the definition of the statistic $X^2$ (the eponymous chi squared):

$$X^2 = \sum_{i}^{}{ \frac{(observed_i - expected_i)^2}{expected_i} }$$

Both series should be of the same order, so one of them needs to be scaled to the other. One can scale `expected` to `observed`.

Below is some Python code that encapsulates this test. To make the final evaluation, a decision is made against the test's resulting p-value.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

def ComputeChiSquareGOF(expected, observed):
    """
    Runs a chi-square goodness-of-fit test and returns the p-value.
    Inputs:
    - expected: numpy array of expected values.
    - observed: numpy array of observed values.
    Returns: p-value
    """
    expected_scaled = expected / float(sum(expected)) * sum(observed)
    result = stats.chisquare(f_obs=observed, f_exp=expected_scaled)
    return result[1]

def MakeDecision(p_value):
    """ 
    Makes a goodness-of-fit decision on an input p-value.
    Input: p_value: the p-value from a goodness-of-fit test.
    Returns: "different" if the p-value is below 0.05, "same" otherwise
    """  
    return "different" if p_value < 0.05 else "same"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    expected = np.array([122319, 295701, 101195])
    observed1 = np.array([1734, 3925, 1823])
    observed2 = np.array([122, 295, 101])

    p_value = ComputeChiSquareGOF(expected, observed1)
    print "Comparing distributions %s vs %s = %s" % \
        (expected, observed1, MakeDecision(p_value))

    p_value = ComputeChiSquareGOF(expected, observed2)
    print "Comparing distributions %s vs %s = %s" % \
        (expected, observed2, MakeDecision(p_value))
```

The output from running this test is:

```
Comparing distributions [122319 295701 101195] vs [1734 3925 1823] = different
Comparing distributions [122319 295701 101195] vs [122 295 101] = same
```